# Configure feature module(s) sharing service

Tags: javascript, angular, module

> Three Modules as depicted...

```
|Elements| and |myForms| are imported into |App|.
```

> Folder Structure

--app

|--Elements angular module (has ConfigService in it).

|--App angular module (angular imports Elements, and myForms (NPM PKG))

> **Elements** module exports **ConfigService** using *forRoot*.

```
export class ElementsModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ElementsModule,
      providers: [ConfigService]
    };
  }
}
```

> **App** module imports **Elements** and **myForms** modules.

```
import { Elements } from './local-dir';
import { myForms } from 'NPM PACKAGE';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Elements.forRoot(),
    myForms
  ]
})
```

> How would I give **myForms** access to the **ConfigService** in a component?

The *forRoot* method is working as I have access in the **App** module like so.

```
import { ElementsModule, ConfigService } form './local-dir';
```

I would like to give it to a **myForms** service that **myForms** already knows about. Or find a way in which I don't have to directly import the file into the **myForms** component I want to use it in.

If I go into the **myForms** NPM PACKAGE, I can do the following and it will work of course.

```
import { ConfigService } from './local-dir';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-element',
  providers: [ConfigService]
});

export class MyElementComponent {

  constructor(private CS: ConfigService){} 
}
```

> **Update** - further clarification.

- There is one app module.
- The app module imports a myForms module. This module requires info from another module that will also be loaded.
- The other module that will be loaded, is one of many that will be choses from. But in the end, only one will be chosen.
- when the chosen module shows up in the app module, I then want to share something it has with the myForms module, inside of the app module. This is a one time share, the myForms modules does not require communication after this.
- The chosen module hands over a key/value of { anyKey: chosenModuleClassNamesToken }.
- Then in the myForms module, I can call the shared data to get class names from the chosen module like this: myFormsService[ chosenModuleDataKey ]. This would result in a value of a class from the chosen module, that I would then build in the view using ComponentFactoryResolver.

Answer (score 1):

Create a barrel file `index.ts`

```
export * from '....' path to your module
export * from '....' path to your service
```

Assuming the below folder structure,

```
---modules
       |---- elements
       |---- configuration
```

Create a barrel file inside the elements folder naming it as `index.ts`

```
export * from './elements.module';
export * from '../configuration/configuration.service';
```

Use this file to import in a single line as

```
import { ElementsModule, ConfigService } from '../elements';
```

Comment: Where would I import the single line you mentioned?

Comment: i didnt understand your question please elaborate

Comment: To be clear, I do not understand how I would be able to DI ConfigService into a Forms module component using your supplied answer.

Comment: why do you want to inject into `FormsModule`? also is it a `@angular/forms` one??

Comment: It is not the FormsModule for angular. I will rename. Its just an example. I will also re-clarify what I would like to do shortly.